# Go and typescript difference base64 encoding problem

Tags: typescript, go, base64

type script:

`Buffer.from('Мегафон').toString('base64') //0JzQtdCz0LDRhNC+0L0=`

go:

`decode, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString("0JzQtdCz0LDRhNC+0L0=") //err : illegal base64 data at input byte 15`

if i try:

`base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("Мегафон")) //0JzQtdCz0LDRhNC-0L0=`

That is, the difference is only in + and -.

I made it work with
`v = strings.ReplaceAll(v, "+", "-")`
but this is clearly not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing "standard" base64 encoding with [URL-safe base64 encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5). To use normal base64 encoding in Go don't use `base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString` but instead `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString`.

Comment: yes this is the solution, only base64.DecodeString doesn't work, should be base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString. and how do I encode in  URL-safe base64 in typescript?

Comment: @Alex12345: *"should be base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString."* - fixed. *"URL-safe base64 in typescript?"* - a quick search shows [url-safe-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-safe-base64).

Answer (score 0):

You encoded your string with standard base64 encoding, and decoded with url-safe decoder. Check out `base64.go`

```golang
// StdEncoding is the standard base64 encoding, as defined in
// RFC 4648.
var StdEncoding = NewEncoding(encodeStd)

// URLEncoding is the alternate base64 encoding defined in RFC 4648.
// It is typically used in URLs and file names.
var URLEncoding = NewEncoding(encodeURL)
```

This will works.

```golang
base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("0JzQtdCz0LDRhNC+0L0=")
```

If you want to encode your string url-safely, use `base64url` instead of `base64`. Then you can decode the string with `base64.URLEncoding`.

```js
 Buffer.from('Мегафон').toString('base64url'); //'0JzQtdCz0LDRhNC-0L0'
```